# Using same Map in several classes after Serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

My app is saving a hashmap before it stops and when it starts again loads the same hashmap so changes could be made to it. I am using Serialization.

Storage class:

```
public class Storage {

private Map<String, String> storage;
private String projectStorageFilePath;

public Storage() {
    this.storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    makeDir();
}

/**
 * If the file in which the map objects will be saved doesn't exist in the
 * user home directory it creates it.
 */
private void makeDir() {
    File projectHomeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".TestMap");
    String projectHomeDirPath = projectHomeDir.getAbsolutePath();
    File projectStorageFile = new File(projectHomeDirPath, "storage.save");
    projectStorageFilePath = projectStorageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    if (!projectHomeDir.exists()) {
        projectHomeDir.mkdir();
        try {
            projectStorageFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean load() {
    boolean isLoaded = false;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {

        File file = new File(projectStorageFilePath);
        if (file.length() != 0) {

            //loading the map 
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            storage = (ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>) ois.readObject();

            isLoaded = true;

        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != ois) {
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return isLoaded;
}

public boolean save() {
    boolean isSaved = false;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {

        //saving
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(projectStorageFilePath));
        oos.writeObject(storage);

        isSaved = true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != oos) {
                oos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return isSaved;
}

public Map<String, String> getStorage() {
    return this.storage;
}
}
```

The class in which I am trying to do something with that hashmap:

```
public class DoSomethingWithMap {

private Map<String, String> storage;

public DoSomethingWithMap(Map<String, String> storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
}

public void addToMap(String key, String value) {
    this.storage.put(key, value);
}
public void printMap() {
    System.out.println(this.storage);
}
}
```

When I run it the first time it works fine:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Storage s = new Storage();
    DoSomethingWithMap something = new DoSomethingWithMap(s.getStorage());

    if (s.load()) {
        System.out.println(s.getStorage());
    }

    something.addToMap("2", "test2");
    something.addToMap("4", "test4");
    something.addToMap("5", "test5");

    if (s.save()) {
        System.out.println(s.getStorage());
    }
 }
}
```

Output:

```
{}           //empty map which is ok because it has never been saved before
{3=test3, 4=test4, 5=test5} //changes during runtime are saved
```

The problem is when I start Main again and try to make changes to the saved map:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Storage s = new Storage();
    DoSomethingWithMap something = new DoSomethingWithMap(s.getStorage());

    if (s.load()) {
        System.out.println(s.getStorage());
    }

    something.printMap();

    something.addToMap("6", "newTest");
    something.addToMap("7", "newTest");
    something.addToMap("8", "newTest");

    something.printMap();

    if (s.save()) {
        System.out.println(s.getStorage());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{3=test3, 4=test4, 5=test5}         //loading the map works fine
{}                                 //here it should be same as previous line but is not
{6=newTest, 7=newTest, 8=newTest} //DoSomethingWithMap.printMap is printing only the changes during runtime
{3=test3, 4=test4, 5=test5}      // changes during runtime are not saved
```

It is obvious DoSomethingWithMap class is not using the map which was given to it. Why? Which map is using? How I can fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: Try make the HashMap Static in the doSomething method

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the Map in your load method:

```
storage = (ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>) ois.readObject();
```

To fix you can clear the current map and then add all the values from the loaded one:

```
//loading the map
ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
storage.clear();
storage.putAll((ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>) ois.readObject());
```

To prevent such error in the future, you could make those fields final and thus you will get error reports.

Comment: I didn't know I am creating new instance of storage. Thank you for clearing it up.